# Running a regression model over 30 specific set.seed automatically using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

I am working with several linear regression models.

I want to run a linear regression model with different 30 set.seed

For clarification, I only share the code with two regression models and 10 set.seed (In my project I have 12 regression models and each one should be run with 30 different set.seeds)

I need a solution that I can run a 30 set.seed for one linear regression model so I can go away from my laptop during the running period (30 set.seeds). Then I did the same for the second regression model.

Is there a way to run the code over the 30 different set.seed automatically. So I got a result for each set.seed.

I hope everything is clear and I am happy to clarify more.

**NOTE**

Bear in mind that I have four related Blocks with each regression model. So any change with set.seed or creatFolds may affect the other blocks.

**EDIT1**

The [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Airfoil+Self-Noise) used

```
wdbc <- read.delim("airfoil_self_noise.dat",header=F)
wdbcc=as.data.frame(scale(wdbc))
#set.seed(1)
#set.seed(2)
#set.seed(3)
#set.seed(4)
...
k = 30
folds <- createFolds(wdbcc$V6, k = k, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)

## Ordinary Least Square regression ##
#Block A
lm = list()
for (i in 1:k) {
  lm[[i]] = lm(V6~ ., data = wdbcc[folds[[i]],])
}

#Block B
lm_coef = list()
lm_coef_var = list()
for(j in 1:(lm[[1]]$coefficients %>% length())){
  for(i in 1:k){
    lm_coef[[i]] = lm[[i]]$coefficients[j] 
    lm_coef_var[[j]] = lm_coef %>% unlist() %>% var()
  }
}

#Block C
lm_var = unlist(lm_coef_var)
lm_df = cbind(coefficients = lm[[1]]$coefficients%>% names() %>% as.data.frame()
              , variance = lm_var %>% as.data.frame()) 
colnames(lm_df) = c("coefficients", "variance_lm")

#Block D
lm_var_sum = sum(lm_var)
```

***PQSQ-Regression***

```
X=list()
Y=list()
for (i in 1:k) {
  n=wdbcc[folds[[i]],-6]
  m=wdbcc[folds[[i]],6]
  X[[i]]=n
  Y[[i]]=m
}

#Block A
lmPQSQ1 = list()
for (i in 1:k) {
  lmPQSQ1[[i]] = PQSQRegression(X[[i]],Y[[i]],0.01,data = wdbcc[folds[[i]],])
}

lmmPQSQ1=list()
for (i in 1:k) {
  L=list(coefficients = c(lmPQSQ1[[i]][[2]],lmPQSQ1[[i]][[1]]))
  lmmPQSQ1[[i]]=L
}
#Block B
lm_coefPQSQ1 = list()
lm_coef_varPQSQ1 = list()
for(j in 1:(lmmPQSQ1[[1]]$coefficients %>% length())){
  for(i in 1:k){
    lm_coefPQSQ1[[i]] = lmmPQSQ1[[i]]$coefficients[j] 
    lm_coef_varPQSQ1[[j]] = lm_coefPQSQ1 %>% unlist() %>% var()
  }
}

#Block C
lm_varPQSQ1 = unlist(lm_coef_varPQSQ1)
lm_dfPQSQ1 = variance = lm_varPQSQ1 %>% as.data.frame()
#Block D
PQSQ1_var_sum = sum(lm_varPQSQ1)
```

Comment: add `createFolds` to your `for` loop and use `i` as your seed

Comment: @rawr, could you clarify this more, please.

Comment: `for (i in 1:k) {set.seed(k); folds <- createFolds(...); lm[[ii]] <- lm(..., data = wdbcc[folds, ])}`

Comment: @rawr, I tried but does not work. It gives me "Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'"

Comment: shouldn´t it be: `for (i in 1:k) {set.seed(i); folds <- createFolds(...); lm[[i]] <- lm(..., data = wdbcc[folds, ])}`? Although i am not sure if createFolds is affected by the seed. @jeza it would be much easier to help you, if you share your data / sample data, e.g with `dput()`,...

Comment: @Tonio Liebrand, thanks, I added the dataset to the question. I have many datasets I only add one.

Comment: @Tonio Liebrand, your solution gives me "Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to regress `V6` on all the other variables using both OLS and a LAD model. You want to select `k=30` random "folds" using `createFolds` and repeat the process also `n=30` times. As result you want the variances for each repetition and each coefficient.

I would wrap the fitting part into a function `FX`. Generate `n=30` seeds with `sample`, loop over it with an `lapply` to repeat `FX` `n=30` times.

```
FX <- function(seed, data, k=30) {
  set.seed(seed)  ## sets seed for each iteration
  folds <- createFolds(data[, "V6"], k=k, list=TRUE, returnTrain=TRUE)  ## folds
  ## OLS
  lm1 <- lapply(folds, function(folds) lm(V6 ~ ., data=data[folds, ]))
  lm.coefs <- t(sapply(lm1, coef))  ## lm coefficients
  ## LAD
  lad1 <- lapply(folds, function(folds) lad(V6 ~ ., data=data[folds, ], method="BR"))
  lad.coefs <- t(sapply(lad1, coef))  ## lad coefficients
  ## calculate column variances for both coef matrices
  ## use `attr<-` to add the seed as an attribute if you want
  return(`attr<-`(cbind(lm=apply(lm.coefs, 2, var), lad=apply(lad.coefs, 2, var)),
                  "seed", seed))
}

seeds <- 1:30  ## specific seeds 1, 2, ... 30
## if you want non-consecutive specific seeds, do:
# set.seed(42)                ## set some initial seed
# n <- 30                     ## n. o. seeds
# seeds <- sample(1:1e6, n)   ## sample seeds for `FX`


res <- lapply(seeds, FX, data=wdbcc)  ## lapply loop
```

### Result

This results in a list of length 30 with variance matrices for each repetition, each model, and each coefficient.

```
res[1:2]  ## first two lists
# [[1]]
#                       lm          lad
# (Intercept) 9.104280e-06 1.273920e-05
# V1          2.609623e-05 6.992753e-05
# V2          7.082099e-05 2.075875e-05
# V3          1.352299e-05 1.209651e-05
# V4          7.986000e-06 9.273005e-06
# V5          5.545298e-05 1.535849e-05
# attr(,"seed")
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
#                       lm          lad
# (Intercept) 4.558722e-06 2.031707e-05
# V1          2.256583e-05 9.291900e-05
# V2          6.519648e-05 2.768443e-05
# V3          1.800889e-05 9.983524e-06
# V4          1.131813e-05 1.174496e-05
# V5          3.866105e-05 1.022452e-05
# attr(,"seed")
# [1] 2

length(res)
# [1] 30
```

To calculate the sum of variances for each seed you may use `colSums` in an `sapply`.

```
# sum of variances
sov <- t(sapply(res, colSums))

dim(sov)
# [1] 30  2

head(sov)
#                lm          lad
# [1,] 1.829835e-04 0.0001401535
# [2,] 1.603091e-04 0.0001728735
# [3,] 1.003093e-04 0.0001972869
# [4,] 1.460591e-04 0.0001508251
# [5,] 9.915082e-05 0.0001262106
# [6,] 1.425996e-04 0.0001478449
```

---

To understand what one iteration of the `lapply` does, consider this:

```
## provide the values of first iteration for arguments of function `FX`
seed <- 1
data <- wdbcc
k <- 30
```

```
## first iteration of `lapply`
set.seed(seed)
folds <- createFolds(data[, "V6"], k=k, list=TRUE, returnTrain=TRUE)  ## folds
## OLS
lm1 <- lapply(folds, function(folds) lm(V6 ~ ., data=data[folds, ]))
lm.coefs <- t(sapply(lm1, coef))  ## lm coefficients

dim(lm.coefs)
# [1] 30  6
head(lm.coefs)
#          (Intercept)         V1         V2         V3        V4         V5
# Fold01 -0.0039130125 -0.5806272 -0.3564769 -0.4804492 0.2271908 -0.2805472
# Fold02  0.0013260444 -0.5863764 -0.3533327 -0.4759213 0.2253128 -0.2874691
# Fold03  0.0006791787 -0.5890787 -0.3678586 -0.4832066 0.2220979 -0.2739124
# Fold04 -0.0010721593 -0.5868079 -0.3722466 -0.4895328 0.2227811 -0.2749657
# Fold05  0.0021856620 -0.5850165 -0.3495360 -0.4810657 0.2235410 -0.2936287
# Fold06  0.0001486909 -0.5872607 -0.3677774 -0.4848523 0.2275780 -0.2823764
```

```
## LAD (same as OLS)
lad1 <- lapply(folds, function(folds) lad(V6 ~ ., data=data[folds, ], method="BR"))
lad.coefs <- t(sapply(lad1, coef))  ## lad coefficients
```

```
## return, throws variances for each coefficient of each model in a matrix
## the seed is added as an attribute, to be able to identify it later
res.1 <- `attr<-`(cbind(var.lm=apply(lm.coefs, 2, var), 
                        var.lad=apply(lad.coefs, 2, var)),
                  "seed", seed)
res.1
#                   var.lm      var.lad
# (Intercept) 9.104280e-06 1.273920e-05
# V1          2.609623e-05 6.992753e-05
# V2          7.082099e-05 2.075875e-05
# V3          1.352299e-05 1.209651e-05
# V4          7.986000e-06 9.273005e-06
# V5          5.545298e-05 1.535849e-05
# attr(,"seed")
# [1] 1
```

Compare `res.1` with the first element of list `res` above.

```
sov.1 <- colSums(res.1)
sov.1
#       var.lm      var.lad 
# 0.0001829835 0.0001401535
```

Compare `sov.1` with the first row of matrix `sov` above.

---

## Edit

For **regression functions with matrix notation**, such as `lm.fit`, we may use `model.matrix` and do the subsetting beforehand, see line `lm2.coefs` in the function; compare `lm` and `lm2` columns in `res2` below, they're equal. (`lm.fit` is also faster than `lm`, because it omits unnecessary calculations, and you just need the coefficients; hence you may actually replace `lm` with `lm.fit` line. There might also be a way with `lad` using `lsfit` in the code, but honestly I'm too unfamiliar with `lad` to provide you this solution.)

Also notice, that, for sake of brevity I merged the two lines per model into one using `sapply` directly on the `$coefficients`. `sapply` works as `lapply` but throws a matrix; note that we need to `t`ranspose.

```
FX2 <- function(seed, data, k=30) {
  set.seed(seed)  ## sets seed for each iteration
  folds <- createFolds(data[, "V6"], k=k, list=TRUE, returnTrain=TRUE)  ## draw folds
  lm.coefs <- t(sapply(folds, function(f) lm(V6 ~ ., data=data[f, ])$coef))
  lm2.coefs <- t(sapply(folds, function(f) {
    data2 <- data[f, ]
    lm.fit(x=model.matrix(V6 ~ ., data2), y=data2[,"V6"])$coef
    }))
  lad.coefs <- t(sapply(folds, function(f) lad(V6 ~ ., data=data[f, ], method="BR")$coef))
  return(`attr<-`(cbind(lm=apply(lm.coefs, 2, var), 
                        lm2=apply(lm2.coefs, 2, var), 
                        lad=apply(lad.coefs, 2, var)),
                  "seed", seed))
}

seeds <- 1:30 
res.2 <- lapply(seeds, FX2, data=wdbcc)  ## lapply loop
res.2[1:2]
# [[1]]
#                       lm          lm2          lad
# (Intercept) 9.104280e-06 9.104280e-06 1.273920e-05
# V1          2.609623e-05 2.609623e-05 6.992753e-05
# V2          7.082099e-05 7.082099e-05 2.075875e-05
# V3          1.352299e-05 1.352299e-05 1.209651e-05
# V4          7.986000e-06 7.986000e-06 9.273005e-06
# V5          5.545298e-05 5.545298e-05 1.535849e-05
# attr(,"seed")
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
#                       lm          lm2          lad
# (Intercept) 4.558722e-06 4.558722e-06 2.031707e-05
# V1          2.256583e-05 2.256583e-05 9.291900e-05
# V2          6.519648e-05 6.519648e-05 2.768443e-05
# V3          1.800889e-05 1.800889e-05 9.983524e-06
# V4          1.131813e-05 1.131813e-05 1.174496e-05
# V5          3.866105e-05 3.866105e-05 1.022452e-05
# attr(,"seed")
# [1] 2
```

---

---

*Data and libraries:*

```
invisible(lapply(c("caret", "L1pack"), library, character.only=TRUE))
wdbcc <- read.delim("airfoil_self_noise.dat", header=F)
wdbcc[] <- lapply(wdbcc, scale)
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer. What I want is to regress V6 on all the other variables using both OLS and a LAD model. I want to select k=30 random "folds" using createFolds and "Using 30 specific set.seed (1,2,3,...30).  As a result, with the first set.seed for example, and the first model OLS، I access 30 folds variation model to the coefficients and calculate the variance of the coefficients for each variable and then sum the variance for all the variables. Then I will do the same for the second set.seed and so on. Finally, I will perform the same for the second model.

Comment: @jeza So in `res` you want to sum the variances of each column (i.e. model), that are now stored in the 30 matrices? If so, would `t(sapply(res, colSums))` yield what you want (note, however, that the intercept is included)? For specific seed see my edit around the seed line.

Comment: thanks for your answer, since I created 30 folds, I should get 30 models output (coefficients parameter for each variable) for the first set.seed(1), and 30 models for the second.set seed(2) and the same for the rest set.seed(3,..30). Then, I calculate the variance of the coefficients for each variable (I will have 30 coefficients value for each variable) and then sum the variance for all the variables(aggregated variance). However, your code gives a model for each set.seed.

Comment: @jeza I'm not sure if you understand the `lapply` approach right. I am currently convinced that the code does exactly what you want. I've broken down the first iteration of the `lapply` for you as an edit to my answer. Perhaps I have not yet understood exactly what you want; in that case I would ask for more clarification.

Comment: thank you so much, the problem now is solved. However, I tried to use the same idea with PQSQ regression but does not work. PQSQ regression function requires the function input to be as X, Y. It is not like the normal linear regression (V6~.). The code of the PQSQ regression that I added to the question is working but what I want is to automate over set.seed.

Comment: @jeza I don't know the `PQSQRegression` function and didn't find it in a quick internet search; but it seems to require matrix notation as opposed to formula notation. `lm.fit` works on the same principle, and I added it to the function in line `lm2.coefs <-`.

Comment: It works! I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much. You deserve more than best wishes.